# pip installs packages successfully, but executables not found from command line

Tags: python, macos, pip, macports

I am working on mac OS X Yosemite, version 10.10.3.

I installed python2.7 and pip using macport as done in 
http://johnlaudun.org/20150512-installing-and-setting-pip-with-macports/

I can successfully install packages and import them inside my python environment and python scripts. However any executable associated with a package that can be called from the command line in the terminal are not found.

**Does anyone know what might be wrong?** (More details below)

For example while installing a package called "rosdep" as instructed in http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source

I can run: `sudo pip install -U rosdep`
which installs without errors and corresponding files are located in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

However if I try to run : `sudo rosdep init`,
it gives an error : `"sudo: rosdep: command not found"`

This is not a package specific error. I get this for any package installed using pip on my computer. I even tried adding

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

to my `$PATH`.
But the executables are not found on the command line, even though the packages work perfectly from within python.

Comment: any virtualenv involved?

Comment: no, no virtualenv is involved.

Comment: when you sudo, you switch to the $PATH of the root user, just make sure his PATH is updated, not your PATH

Answer (score 73, accepted):

check your $PATH

`tox` has a command line mode:

```
audrey:tests jluc$ pip list | grep tox
tox (2.3.1)
```

where is it?

(edit:  the `2.7` stuff doesn't matter much here, sub in any `3.x` and pip's behaving pretty much the same way)

```
audrey:tests jluc$ which tox
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/tox
```

and what's in my $PATH?

```
audrey:tests jluc$ echo $PATH
/opt/chefdk/bin:/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin:/opt/local/bin:..../opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin...
```

Notice the **/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin**?  That's what allows finding my pip-installed stuff

Now, to see where things are from Python, try doing this (substitute `rosdep` for `tox`).

```
$python
>>> import tox
>>> tox.__file__
```

that prints out:

```
'/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.pyc'
```

Now, **cd** to the directory right above `lib` in the above.  Do you see a **bin** directory?  Do you see `rosdep` in that bin?  If so try adding the `bin` to your $PATH.

```
audrey:2.7 jluc$ cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
audrey:2.7 jluc$ ls -1
```

output:

```
Headers
Python
Resources
bin
include
lib
man
share
```

Answer (score 164):

I know the question asks about macOS, but here is a solution for **Linux** users who arrive here via Google.

I was having the issue described in this question, having installed the [pdfx](https://github.com/metachris/pdfx) package via pip.

When I ran it however, nothing...

```
pip list | grep pdfx
pdfx (1.3.0)
```

Yet:

```
which pdfx
pdfx not found
```

The problem on Linux is that `pip install ...` drops scripts into `~/.local/bin` and this is not on the default Debian/Ubuntu `$PATH`.

Here's a GitHub issue going into more detail: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3813

To fix, just add `~/.local/bin` to your `$PATH`, for example by adding the following line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

After that, restart your shell and things should work as expected.

Answer (score 137):

## Solution

Based on other answers, for `linux` and `mac` you can run the following:

```sh
echo "export PATH=\"`python3 -m site --user-base`/bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

instead of `python3` you can use any other link to python version: `python`, `python2.7`, `python3.6`, `python3.9`, etc.

instead of .bashrc, choose the rc file from your favourite shell.

### Explanation

In order to know where the user packages are installed in the current OS (win, mac, linux), we run:

```sh
python3 -m site --user-base
```

We know that the scripts go to the `bin/` folder where the packages are installed.

So we concatenate the paths:

```sh
echo `python3 -m site --user-base`/bin
```

Then we export that to an environment variable.

```sh
export PATH=\"`python3 -m site --user-base`/bin:\$PATH\"
```

Finally, in order to avoid repeating the export command we add it to our `.bashrc` file and we run `source` to run the new changes, giving us the suggested solution mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: wonder why in my case path is wrong, but python binary is used from macports..?  $ python3 -m site --user-base 
/Users/macpro/Library/Python/3.11
$ which python3
/opt/local/bin/python3

Comment: I would add the following to your run command file so it will update everytime you update python: export PATH="$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Backslashes are incorrect! What worked for me is  `export PATH=$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 91):

On macOS with the default python installation you need to add `/Users/<you>/Library/Python/2.7/bin/` to your $PATH.

Add this to your .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Users/<you>/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"
```

That's where pip installs the executables.

Tip: For non-default python version `which python` to find the location of your python installation and replace that portion in the path above. (Thanks for the hint Sanket_Diwale)

Answer (score 65):

## Solution

Add this to your `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, or equivalent shellrc file:

```bash
# Add Python bin directories to path
python3.11 -m site &> /dev/null && PATH="$PATH:`python3.11 -m site --user-base`/bin"
```

If you need Python 2, add this too:

```bash
python2.7 -m site &> /dev/null && PATH="$PATH:`python2.7 -m site --user-base`/bin"
```

## More Info

If you're installing using `--user` (e.g. `pip3.6 install --user tmuxp`), [it is possible to get the platform-specific user install directory from Python itself using the `site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#cmdoption-site-user-base).  For example, on macOS:

```bash
$ python2.7 -m site --user-base
/Users/alexp/Library/Python/2.7
```

By appending `/bin` to this, we now have the path where package executables will be installed.

We can dynamically populate the `PATH` in your shell's rc file based on the output; I'm using bash, but with any luck this is portable:

```bash
# Add Python bin directories to path
python3.11 -m site &> /dev/null && PATH="$PATH:`python3.11 -m site --user-base`/bin"
python2.7 -m site &> /dev/null && PATH="$PATH:`python2.7 -m site --user-base`/bin"
```

### Why the exact versions (3.11) and not just the major version (3)?

I use the precise Python versions to reduce the chance of the executables just "disappearing" when Python upgrades a minor version, e.g. from 3.5 to 3.6.  They'll disappear because, as can be seen above, the user installation path may include the Python version.  So while `python3` could point to 3.5, 3.6, 3.11 etc., `python3.6` will always point to 3.6.  This needs to be kept in mind when installing further packages, e.g. use `pip3.6` over `pip3`.

If you don't mind the idea of packages disappearing, you can use `python2` and `python3` instead:

```bash
# Add Python bin directories to path
# Note: When Python is upgraded, packages may need to be re-installed
#       or Python versions managed.
python3 -m site &> /dev/null && PATH="$PATH:`python3 -m site --user-base`/bin"
python2 -m site &> /dev/null && PATH="$PATH:`python2 -m site --user-base`/bin"
```

Answer (score 28):

The [Installing Packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages) tutorial on python.org describes how to locate the binary directory:

**On Windows**

> You can find the user base binary directory by running
> `python -m site --user-site` and replacing `site-packages` with `Scripts`.
> For example, this could return
> `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python36\site-packages` so you
> would need to set your PATH to include
> `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python36\Scripts`.

**On Linux and macOS**

> On Linux and macOS you can find the user base binary directory by
> running `python -m site --user-base` and adding `bin` to the end. For
> example, this will typically print `~/.local` (with `~` expanded to the
> absolute path to your home directory) so you’ll need to add
> `~/.local/bin` to your PATH.

Comment: "python -m site --user-site and replacing site-packages with Scripts" this is it , what worked

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled upon this question because I created, successfully built and published a PyPI Package, but couldn't execute it after installation. The `$PATH`variable was correctly set.

In my case the problem was that I hadn't set the `entry_point`in the `setup.py` file:

```
entry_points = {'console_scripts':

['YOUR_CONSOLE_COMMAND=MODULE_NAME.FILE_NAME:FUNCTION_NAME'],},
```

Answer (score 8):

### Windows and Python 3.9 from MS Store

I have a different path with `python -m site --user-base` and `python -m site` - yes, the second command without `--user-base` to get all sites - as the other answers here state:

`C:\Users\<your User>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages`

#### Why is my path different

Because I installed `python` from MS Store

#### Solution

Put the above path in your path and replace `site-packages` with `scripts`

Answer (score 7):

I solve the problem!

1. Use `pip3` instead `pip`.
2. `pip3 install foobaz`
3. `vim ~/.zshrc` and add:

```bash
export PATH="/Users/your_name/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

4. `source ~/.zshrc`

> Now MacOS has shifted the default terminal from `bash` to `zsh`. Therefore, you have to source zshrc but not bashrc or bash_profile.

5. `foobaz -v`

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, you need to add the path `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts` to your path.

Comment: This directory does not exist on my (Windows) machine.

Answer (score 4):

When you install Python or Python3 using MacOS installer (downloaded from Python website) - it adds an `export`er to your `~/.profile` script. All you need to do is just `source` it. Restarting all the terminals should also do the trick.

WARNING - I believe it's better to just use pip3 with Python3 - for future benefits.

If you already have Python3 installed, the following steps work for me on macOS Mojave:

1. Install ansible first using `sudo` - `sudo -H pip3 install ansible`
2. you create a symlink to the Python's `bin` path

`sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/current_python_bin`

and staple it to `.profile`

`export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/current_python_bin`

3. run `source ~/.profile` and restart all terminal shells.
4. Type `ansible --version`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding python's `bin` directory to `$PATH` variable, I also had to change the owner of that directory, to make it work. No idea why I wasn't the owner already.

```
chown -R ~/Library/Python/
```

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue with macOS Monterey. I had to modify my `.bash_profile` file and add the following entry

```
export PATH="~/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

The default python version on macOS Monterey is 3.8, but you will have to double check your python version to make sure you're using the correct one