# How do I enter an emoji into a string in Vim?

Tags: vim, unicode, emoji

Couldn't figure this out.  Just need to enter 1 emoji into a string and couldn't figure it out.  Unicode is not working.  Tried diagraph but didn't work either.  Is there some trick to this in Vim?  thx!

Comment: http://junegunn.kr/2014/06/emoji-completion-in-vim/

Comment: thanks.  Was hoping for a way to just enter it without adding a whole plugin.  Not that big of a deal to add a plugin just seems like there has to be another way.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You do not need to install a plugin for this. All you need to do is enter the unicode value of the emoji. You can do that in insert mode with `<C-v>`. From `:h i_ctrl-v_digit`:

```
                        *i_CTRL-V_digit*
With CTRL-V the decimal, octal or hexadecimal value of a character can be
entered directly.  This way you can enter any character, except a line break
(<NL>, value 10).  There are five ways to enter the character value:

first char  mode         max nr of chars   max value ~
(none)      decimal        3        255
o or O      octal          3        377      (255)
x or X      hexadecimal    2        ff       (255)
u           hexadecimal    4        ffff     (65535)
U           hexadecimal    8        7fffffff (2147483647)
```

For example, if you want to enter [this smiley-face](http://emojipedia.org/smiling-face-with-smiling-eyes/), which has a unicode value of `U+1F60A`, you could simply type:

```
<C-v>U1F60A<esc>
```

or if you don't want to hit `<esc>`,

```
<C-v>U0001F60A
```

Just so you know, there's a good chance that it will not render properly in vim, depending on your font. If you are using gvim, you can change `:se guifont=*`, or in regular vim, changing your consoles font to make it render (assuming you pick a font that can render this particular emoji)

Comment: I succeeded entering a smiley face per your example. But I am trying to enter ❤️, which comes up with two code points, "U+2764, U+FE0F". Not sure how to enter that!

Answer (score 23):

Another approach is to use abbreviations.

I added a few in my [.vimrc file](https://github.com/bitifet/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/vimrc_files/emoji.vim) and now I just type :pushpin: for , :bulb: for , :bomb: for , etc...

```
" Emoji shortcuts
ab :white_check_mark: ✅
ab :warning: ⚠
ab :bulb: 
ab :pushpin: 
ab :bomb: 
ab :pill: 
ab :construction: 
ab :pencil: 
ab :point_right: 
ab :book: 
ab :link: 
ab :wrench: 
ab :info: 
ab :telephone: 
ab :email: 
ab :computer:
```

There are a lot more of them on [emojicopy.com](https://www.emojicopy.com/) or similar sites. I just picked a few I already used before.

Comment: Nice; the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57027637/211827) links specifically to [emoji-ab](https://gitlab.com/gi1242/vim-emoji-ab), and this essentially mirrors what I [utilize system-wide for replacements](https://ghcdn.webcore.io/mac/system-wide-text-replacements.png).

Comment: So looks like I reinvented the wheel again :-D. Thanks for the report @amcgregor

Answer (score 5):

While it is possible to `<c-v>U1f60A<esc>`, it's not practical if you're
responding to email / entering a comment in a web form. I'm not going to
memorize unicode emoji tables  for quick "Thanks " comment.

Few other options for such use cases:

1. Type your usual smileys like `:)` and have a plugin replace it with the
   unicode equivalent . The plugin
   [emoji-ab](https://gitlab.com/gi1242/vim-emoji-ab) does this for you.
2. Type codes like `:boom:`.  Many markdown parsers will convert it to   for
   you. But if you're not using such a parser,
   [emoji-ab](https://gitlab.com/gi1242/vim-emoji-ab) will also convert it for
   you.
3. Use something like
   [gucharmap](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gucharmap?action=show&redirect=Gucharmap)
   (or one of the many online Unicode pickers) to copy and paste unicode
   characters into vim.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to access these emojies in many contexts including Vim is to use the character map dialog window:

- On Mac, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and select the character.
- On Windows, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type the charmap.

[image: Charmap selector image]

Comment: GNOME 3.28 and above (Ubuntu Linux and elsewhere) has an emoji picker, but sadly it doesn't work in GNOME Terminal. See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/use-emoji-linux-ubuntu-apps

Answer (score 2):

You can use emoji-fzf pip package

First install fzf

```
sudo apt install fzf
```

then intall emoji-fzf

```
pip install emoji-fzf
```

now make sure you can run emoji-fzf

```
emoji-fzf --help
```

if you get "comand not found" error please see
[pip installs packages successfully, but executables not found from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line)

now add emoji-fzf to your .vimrc

```
" Use emoji-fzf and fzf to fuzzy-search for emoji, and insert the result
function! InsertEmoji(emoji)
    let @a = system('cut -d " " -f 1 | emoji-fzf get', a:emoji)
    normal! "agP
endfunction

command! -bang Emoj
  \ call fzf#run({
      \ 'source': 'emoji-fzf preview',
      \ 'options': '--preview ''emoji-fzf get --name {1}''',
      \ 'sink': function('InsertEmoji')
      \ })
" Ctrl-e in normal and insert mode will open the emoji picker.
" Unfortunately doesn't bring you back to insert mode 
map <C-e> :Emoj<CR>
imap <C-e> <C-o><C-e>
```

restart your vim and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> and search for your favourite emoji and press <kbd>enter</kbd>