# Pip3 installed packages not found

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When I install a package through pip3 (on my Mac) it is successfully installed however when I try importing it calls an error. How do I fix this for python3?

I have tried multiple libraries and all are the same. However using pip and installing the same packages for python2 it works

```sh
pip3 install pyzbar
```

In Python 3:

```py
import pyzbar
ModuleNotFound Error
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip check pyzbar`? Or perhaps what you want to do is `python3 -m pip install pyzbar`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip installs packages successfully, but executables not found from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line)