# Getting command not found: rasa on using rasa commands

Tags: python, zsh, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have installed `rasa` using:

```
pip3 install rasa
```

When I try to use `rasa` commands like:

```
rasa init
```

I get zsh errors:

> command not found: rasa error

I am on Mac OS Catalina, using:
 
Python version `2.7.16`
Python3 version `3.7.6`
pip version `19.2.3`

My `path` variable looks like this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
:/usr/local/bin
:/usr/bin
:/bin
:/usr/sbin
:/sbin
```

Comment: Does it return anything when you run: `pip list`?

Comment: yes it shows rasa and also shows information when typed pip show rasa as well

Comment: The issue appears to be with the path. Can you check that pip is in your path? `echo $PATH`

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Have you tried any of these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line/35899029

Comment: The question is, where did `pip3` *put* `rasa`?

Comment: yes, i think its a path issue, but i have little idea as how to correct the path on mac, in windows we can set path in environment variables.

Comment: For me `pip install rasa` installs version 0.0.1 of rasa. pip is unable to find any versions newer than 1.10.2. Very puzzling.

Answer (score 4):

## RASA is currently incompatible with python 3.9+

I'm having python 3.10, and have to switch to python 3.8 for working with Rasa.

To save yourself time:

### 1. Install python 3.8

### 2. Create and activate virtual environment:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install virtualenv 
py -3.8 -m virtualenv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
```

### 3. Upgrade pip

```
py -3.8 -m pip install -U pip
```

### 4. Install Rasa

```
pip install rasa
```

### 5. Check installation

```
rasa -h
```

You should see something like:

```
usage: rasa [-h] [--version] {init,run,shell,train,interactive,telemetry,test,visualize,data,export,x,evaluate} ...

Rasa command line interface. Rasa allows you to build your own conversational assistants . The 'rasa' command allows
you to easily run most common commands like creating a new bot, training or evaluating models.
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I also got the similar error in ubuntu, you can try these set of command:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install rasa
```

The first command will update the python package manager and the second will install `rasa`. 
If `pip install rasa` is not working, then you can try `pip3 install rasa`

Answer (score 3):

**I had followed these following steps and it's working fine for me**

Firstly, create a directory name of your choice and get inside of it

```
mkdir rasaprojects #directory name of your choice in place of rasaprojects
cd rasaprojects   #get inside that directory
```

Now create virtual environment of python3

```
virtualenv rasaenv -p python3 #write your environment name instead of rasaenv
```

Now activate the environment

```
source rasaenv/bin/activate
```

Finally you are good to go with rasa installation

```
pip3 install rasa
```

Comment: These steps are for ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I add `~/.local/bin` to my `$PATH` in `.bashrc`, and It resolved the problem:

0. Go to the home directory:

   ```
   cd
   ```
1. Find your file location (for me it was `./.bashrc`):

   ```
   sudo find -name .bashrc
   ```
2. Open `.bashrc` by `nano`:

   ```
   nano ./.bashrc
   ```
3. Add next code at the end of the file:

   ```
   export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
   ```
4. Restart your shell.

Answer (score 0):

You should activate your python env, create a folder with `mkdir` and then open it with `cd` and then: `rasa init --no-prompt (ubuntu user)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downgrading python specifically 3.6.8. However, you can install any version from Python **3.6.x to 3.8.x, and NOT 3.9.**

*Tips: Don't add variable paths while installing multiple versions of python.*

In my case, I had 3.9 python and didn't want to uninstall it because I was a working project on the 3.9 version. If you have the same case, then follow the steps. Otherwise, you can alter `step2 : python -m venv project_name\venv`

Step 1: Install [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) from above given ranges. Again, please don't install python 3.9 because it is not currently compatible.

Step 2: Delete the existing virtual environment, if you have already created it while priviously installing the rasa. Make new one

```
> C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python -m venv project_name\venv
```

(`venv: name of the virtual environment`)

This command allows creating a new virtual environment with python just you installed it through step1. You can check `python -m version`

Step 3: Activate the environment

```
> project_name\venv\Scripts\acitvate.bat
```

Step 4: Finally, start installing the rasa:

```
> pip install rasa
```

Step 5:

```
> rasa init
```

Note: I wasn't using anaconda. If you are currently using an anaconda environment, please do needful with the above steps.

If you still cannot resolve it, please follow [thread](https://forum.rasa.com/t/please-help-i-have-issues-with-installed-rasa-on-windows-10/22676/6) or you can post there your specific query.

Answer (score 0):

other way to do it using docker so will be no issues.
1.make new directory example rasadocker and open terminal or command prompt

2.run following command `docker run --user 1000 -v $(pwd):/app rasa/rasa:3.1.0-full init --no-prompt` here --user 1000 for no error of user permission ,-v is for volume, pwd is current directory, :/app is volume in docker image , rasa/rasa is rasa docker image with tag 3.1.0-full ,important thing here to create a project we use init
3.you can see in current folder project required files are added
4.to play with bot run following command `

`docker run --user 1000 -it -v $(pwd):/app rasa/rasa:3.1.0-full shell` opens shell where bot asks you input

`