# 'rasa' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Unable to run the rasa init command and getting following error:
'rasa' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have following version of RASA in my environment: 
rasa-core           0.13.2
rasa-core-sdk       0.12.2
rasa-nlu            0.14.6
rasa-sdk            1.2.0

Comment: Could you please provide the OS you are using?

Comment: Sure, I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I got the same issue after installing rasa with conda. It worked only after creating a new environment and reinstalling.

Comment: I have already answered this question may help you. please [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71048962/9511113) on it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sams answer is right. Rasa is probably not in your environment variable path.

Have you already tried:

```
py -m rasa init
```

or

```
python -m rasa init
```

If this doesn't work you may find answers at the [rasa community forum](https://forum.rasa.com/)

Answer (score 5):

Did you try pip based installation as mentioned [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/#installation-guide)

You can do

```
pip install rasa
```

If you have already done that I suspect that you need to add rasa in the environment variable **PATH**
Also are you using virtualenv? or conda environment? I would suggest using that to do the installation.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with python 3.9. It worked after downgrading the python version to 3.8. It required recreating my conda environment.

Comment: A very interesting scenario. I was faced with the same problem for python version 3.9.7. I decided to try your suggestion, by setting python == 3.8. And it works like a charm. I wonder why python 3.9 versions have the error.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you got it working by now, but if not you can either

1) Try setting the Python path in `Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables`.  (ideally we want it in a top-level folder)

2) Re-install Python using the graphical installer. Run the regular Python installer as administrator. BE SURE to click the little ‘Add to PATH’ checkbox, or all this will be for naught!! (For me personally this is a lot easier than manually adjusting the path in environment variables.)
Then choose “Custom install location.” Clicking “Install for all users” should automatically change the install path to the C:Program Files folder.

3) You may also be able to do this without a full reinstall by selecting `Programs > Programs and Features > Modify/Repair`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Manage App Execution Aliases -> **Turn Python Off** - since I had both Python and Python3 enabled, the VSCODE was not letting me access the virtual environment I created in the Project Folder. This solved my issue.
Wrong Path in cmd Terminal of VSCODE:
C:\User....\Project>rasa --version
'rasa' was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Correct Path in cmd Terminal of VSCODE (after turning off Python in Computer App Settings):
(venv) C:\User....\Project>rasa --version
Rasa Version : 2.3.4
Rasa SDK Version : 2.3.1
Rasa X Version : 0.37.1
Python Version : 3.7.10

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer says to set the environment variables which made me curious but the problem is I do not know the rasa installation path to set the environment variables.

**Step 1:**
So I'll write down how I figured this out. First, if you don't have the Anaconda package manager install it from the [official website](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). (While installing click the checkbox to add Anaconda to your PATH environment variable.)

**Step 2:**
Now open up the anaconda prompt and go to the directory where you want to run `rasa`.

**Step 3:**
Then we can create a new `conda` environment by running `conda create --name installingrasa python==3.8.5` to keep all of our dependencies together in a centralized place. Finally activate the environment by `conda activate installingrasa`

**Step 4:**
Install UJSON and Tensorflow that will help us to work with `rasa`.

```
conda install ujson
conda install tensorflow
```

**Step 5:**
Ultimately we can install `rasa`. Here we are going to install it via `pip` rather than `conda`. (there is no `conda` version fr rasa at the moment I'm writing this)

```
pip install rasa
```

**Step 6:**
In order to run Tensorflow on windows, we need to download visual c++ separately. Find the executable from the [official website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0). And now we can run `rasa init` without errors and initialize new bot.

Answer (score 0):

try this code while creating a virtual environment

```
conda create --name filename python==3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue of python 3.9. After playing around a lot with 3.9, I downgraded my python to 3.8 and it worked without a glitch.

You can create a conda environment with a different python version by using the option python==3.8 in the conda create command line.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions didn't worked for me.
After a lot of searching I found that rasa was located at C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\rasa.py (installed using pip install rasa)

As I was working anaconda environment named as(RASA)
I didn’t found rasa.py at C:\Users\tejas\anaconda3\envs\RASA\Scripts nor in

C:\Users\tejas\anaconda3\Scripts

So I just copy pasted rasa.py at these 2 locations and it worked for me in anaconda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command,

`pip3 install -U --user pip && pip3 install rasa`

It worked for me, This command will upgrade your pip to the latest version, and rasa will be successfully installed, and check it by typing rasa --version.

If it still doesn't work, download the python 3.7 version using miniconda,set the environment using miniconda, and then install rasa using this command again

Answer (score 0):

You might forget to install the rasa package. You can follow the steps to install rasa on your machine.

- **Create a new virtual environment named `venv`**

  You can also install rasa without virtual environment. but it would be better to track the dependencies if we are in a virtual environment.

  ```
  python3 -m venv venv
  ```
- **Activate the virtual environment**

  For windows: `venv\Scripts\activate`

  For Ubuntu: `source ./venv/bin/activate`
- **Install rasa package**

  ```
  pip3 install -U pip
  pip3 install rasa
  ```

For more: [Rasa installation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/installation/)