# ‘rasa’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, conda, rasa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Kvi.png)

I am getting error : ‘rasa’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I have installed rasa x successfully, still getting above error. Please help.

Comment: Please include the command you used for the installation in your question **as text**. Also always put your error message **as text**. Don't post images

Comment: pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple

Comment: I used above command to in install rasa x in conda environment

Comment: Did you follow the proper guidelines for using Conda with pip? (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['rasa' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880260/rasa-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 0):

I think rasa is not recognized in your anaconda environment variable path. Adding rasa as environment variable should fix your problem.

This question might be similar to [your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880260/rasa-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or/59895593#59895593). It may help :)

---

If adding rasa as environment variable didn't help you can also try to interact with rasa like:

```
py -m rasa init
```

or

```
python -m rasa init
```