# How to run scapy after installing

Tags: packet-sniffers

I have installed scapy using the command **pip install scapy** on my ubuntu terminal. I also have Python 2.7.17 installed. How do I run scapy in the ubuntu terminal? I have tried running the command: **sudo ./scapy**. My goal is to use scapy to sniff packets and record sending and receiving time of packets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip installs packages successfully, but executables not found from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
python -m scapy
```

to start the scapy module (-m) as a CLI tool

Answer (score -2):

scapy is not an executable. Its a library used in python wich can be imported into python code:

import scapy.all as scapy

Then you can call scapy.ARP, scapy.Ether or layers/fields like in your code.

If you want to sniff for information from web for example, you need to inport layers too:

from scapy.layers import http

then you can search and filter using http.HTTPRequest:

```
if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
    print(packet.show())
```

to get an idea what fields you wnat to fetch, ex load from scapy.Raw:

packet[scapy.Raw].load

See documentation:  https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html

Comment: Documentation does reference a command-line executable, as the very first use case. https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html