# Not able to run virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I installed virtual environment using (`pip3 install virtualenv`). it was installed but when I check. This comes up.

```
faculty@Facultys-MacBook-Pro ~ % virtualenv --version   
zsh: command not found: virtualenv
```

Comment: You need to know exactly what directory yo have installed it in and you can run it from inside the directoty

Comment: in the director you will see venv folder. navigate to venv/bin and then activate

Comment: what do you see when you run `which virtualenv`? also if you find out a result from this command, what do you see in your 'PATH' variable? may be the bin location for virtualenv is not in your PATH, then you may have to add it manually.

Comment: Its giving virtualenv not found.How do I add it manually?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you might not have you python libs in your path. which is why it is not  found by zsh.

### Quick fix

I believe you can go with:

```
python3 -m virtualenv <name of the virtual env>
```

This should hopefully work and create your `virtualenv` in the current folder you are in.

### Permanent fix

Some smarter people already went through this issue have a look [pip installs packages successfully, but executables not found from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line)

Comment: I was able to create the virtualenv like you suggested..but when I do (which virtualenv), it stills show virtualenv not found

Comment: Indeed, you need to look into the permanent fix. Quick fix only allows you to successfully create the env.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure the following thing:

virtualenv has been only installed in the folder you used to run the pip commmand. There should be a new directory called `venv` now. Try opening the terminal inside the venv folder `bin` and type the command again.