# Problems with pip und Command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

I am trying to create a Python pip package. This works also well. I can successfully upload and download the package and use it in the Python code. What I can't do is to use the Python package via the command line. In another StackOverflow post I found the link to a tutorial. I tried to follow it. Obviously I made a mistake. Can you guys help me please ?
[Installation of the package via pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z3oh.png)
here you can see that the installation worked. Unfortunately, not the whole script fit on the image.
[Pip does not find the package.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNaru.png)
Unfortunately, I can't embed the images directly, so I'll just embed them as links.

I have created a simple Python package. It represents here only an example. Here you can see the structure of the folder

```
Riffecs
|   .gitignore
|   .pylintrc
|   LICENSE
|   README.md
|   requirements.txt
|   setup.py
|
|
\---riffecs
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
```

Here are the basic files shown.

**main.py**

```py
from . import hello_world

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_world()
```

and **init.py**

```py
def hello_world():
    print("Hello world")
```

In the following you can see the "setup.py". I am of the opinion that I have followed the instructions. But obviously I made a mistake somewhere. Can you please help me to correct this mistake.

```py
import io
import os
import setuptools


def read_description():
    url = "README.md"
    """ Read and Return the description """
    return io.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), url), encoding="utf-8").read()


def def_requirements():
    """ Check PIP Requirements """
    with open('requirements.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file_content:
        pip_lines = file_content.read().splitlines()
    return pip_lines


setuptools.setup(
    name="riffecs",
    version='0.0.3',
    description='test',
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['hello-world=riffecs:hello_world',]},
    long_description=read_description(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    license="MIT",
    keywords="test - riffecs",
    url="https://github.com/Riffecs/riffecs",
    packages=["riffecs"],
    install_requires=def_requirements(),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Intended Audience :: Science/Research",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Can you check if it just a path issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line Or can it be the hyphen? Maybe try a different name?

Comment: You were right, too, by the way. In my arch the path was not yet added. Nevertheless, I also had an error in the setup.py. Thanks :) ``export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `setup.py` file you have this line...

```
entry_points={'console_scripts': ['hello-world=riffecs:hello_world',]},
```

This is the entry point to calling you package via command line.  This configuration is asking the entry point to be `hello-world`, which I tried and it runs fine.

In your image however you run `riffecx` which is not configured as an entrypoint to the package.

If you wanted the entrypoint to be `riffecx`. change the line to:

```
entry_points={'console_scripts': ['riffecx=riffecs:hello_world']},
```

Hope this helped.