# "Sklearn" is not accessed (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

im trying to install sklearn to my PC but even though i've installed it using pip, when I type
`import sklearn`
it says: "sklearn" is not accessed (Pylance)
Import "sklearn" could not be resolved (Pylance)

I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it on the VSCode terminal and on cmd but the problem just persists, can anyone please tell me how to fix

Comment: Have you reloaded your VSCode window after installation? You can use `ctr + shift + p`  and type `reload window`.

Comment: @MarceloPaco Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by realising I was installing "sklearn" rather than "scikit-learn", so yeah i kind of look like an idiot

Comment: Very common footgun that has definitely burned me in the past. Fortunately the Python Package Index is [rolling out a deprecation strategy for the package](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) that should make `pip install sklearn` return an error come December of 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you are running the right copy of Python in your interpreter in VSCode (in the bottom right of your window here)

[image: VSCode screenshot indicating where the interpreter menu is located for the Python extension]

The general issue is that your python installation isn't looking in the right place for where pip is installing packages. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line) has some good discussion on how to fix this.

Marcelo Paco's comment is reasonable - reloading the VSCode window may kick VSCode into realizing which Python interpreter to use.

Comment: The versions are the same, I have checked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. If normal installation doesn't work you can try this:

```
python -m pip install scikit-learn
```