# Why can't the OS find installed Python entry_point console_scripts?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, entry-point

I'm trying to get an example that shows how to install python scripts so they are available on the command line (original example [from this blog](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/)). I'm installing the module

```
pip3 install -e .
```

When I run the command `my_project` at the command prompt (zsh) it just says

```
zsh: command not found: my_project
```

Why wouldn't it be able to find the installed package as a command? My best guess is that it might be a path issue [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line), but that's for an older MacOS and doesn't seem to apply. I'm running Ventura.

The directory structure looks like this:

> entry_points_project/
>
> > setup.py
> > my_project/
> >
> > > **init**.py
> > > **main**.py

The setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="my_project",
    version="0.1.0",
    packages=["my_project"],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "my_project = my_project.__main__:main"
        ]
    },
)
```

The main.py file:
import sys

```
def main(args=None):
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]

    print("This is the main routine.")
    print("It should do something interesting.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```