# python -m for pre-commit

Tags: python, pre-commit

`pip3 install pre-commit`  => installed

i've tried both `python3 -m pre-commit --version` and `$ pre-commit --versio`n and it says module not found

I am using Pycharm and have cloned a repo from Github. When trying to set up my pre-commit hooks, i installed pre-commit in the terminal, however when trying to obtain the version it says module not found but successful in the install. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:group_three_software user$ pip3 install pre-commit
Requirement already satisfied: pre-commit in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cfgv>=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pre-commit) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: identify>=1.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pre-commit) (2.5.26)
Requirement already satisfied: nodeenv>=0.11.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pre-commit) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pre-commit) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv>=20.10.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pre-commit) (20.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nodeenv>=0.11.1->pre-commit) (63.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.7 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.10.0->pre-commit) (0.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.12.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.10.0->pre-commit) (3.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<4,>=3.9.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.10.0->pre-commit) (3.10.0)
Users-MacBook-Pro:group_three_software user$ python3 -m pre-commit --version
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pre-commit
```

tried both

```
python3 -m pre-commit --version
```

and

```
$ pre-commit --version
```

expected to see the version of the pre-commit and to then add a pre-commit configuration & hook scripts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip installs packages successfully, but executables not found from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62151306/11609216). Change `.bashrc` to `.zshrc` if you are using zsh as the default shell.

Answer (score 3):

the module name is `pre_commit`, the executable is `pre-commit` so you want either

```
python -m pre_commit
```

or

```
pre-commit
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit