# python run pre-commit with -m

Tags: python, pre-commit

Python modules can be run with `-m`
for example next command for `pip`

```
python3.10 -m pip install pre-commit
```

It allow you to specify exact python binary to use with command (python3.10 or python3.11).

I have successfully installed pre-commit, but got next:

```
python3.10 -m pre-commit run         
> python.exe: No module named pre-commit

python3.10 -m precommit run  
> python.exe: No module named precommit
```

how to run pre-commit via `python -m` option ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The error is telling you, you have no pre-commit library installed in that machine (or venv). If you are having problems or questions about pre-commit library you should check their website, pre-commit dot com.

Comment: Have edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module name is `pre_commit`, not `pre-commit` (which is the [name of the entry point](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/84f91646bbfb38cd58d56a0f192a05d42b9cdab5/setup.cfg#L34-L36)), so you need to run

```
python -m pre_commit
```

Note the different names that can be set and do not neccessarily have to be the same:

1. The name of the PyPi project, which is what you use with `pip install`
2. The name of the python module, which is the name used with `import` from within a script or when you do `python -m`
3. The name of an entry-point defined in `setup.cfg` or an executable that is placed in the `bin` folder during setup, which is a name that you can directly type in your terminal

Comment: there's a duplicate here but I can't VTC because this is upvoted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76845526/pip3-install-commit-installed-ive-tried-both-python3-m-pre-commit-version

Comment: You can't VTC because the linked dup doesn't have an upvote on its answer. I upvoted there and marked the dup. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: thanks for dup, I was trying to google answer to the question => no result. I have corrected title of the duplicate, hope now it will be searchable