# Unable to Locate 'jupyter' in Terminal Despite Python 3.10's Jupyter Installation

Tags: python-3.x, macos, jupyter

I have Python installed on my macOS system, and I'm trying to use Jupyter Notebook with it. When I run the command `python3 -m jupyter notebook`, it opens Jupyter Notebook successfully. However, when I try to locate the jupyter executable using which jupyter, it says "jupyter not found."

Here are some additional details:

I have `Python 3.10` installed, and the Python packages related to Jupyter are installed as shown by the output of `pip list | grep jupyter`.

```
jupyter                   1.0.0
jupyter_client            8.2.0
jupyter-console           6.6.3
jupyter_core              5.3.0
jupyter-events            0.7.0
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0
jupyter_server            2.7.3
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4
jupyterlab                4.0.6
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2
jupyterlab_server         2.25.0
jupyterlab-widgets        3.0.9
```

Python is located in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10.
```

My bash profile includes the following lines:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$PATH"
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH
```

My `echo $PATH` output is as follows:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

Why am I unable to locate the 'jupyter' executable with `which jupyter`, even though Jupyter Notebook opens correctly using `python3 -m jupyter notebook`? Is there an issue with my PATH or environment configuration?

I know there are similar questions but none of the suggested/previous solutions work for me. I believe whatever is causing this behavior is also responsible for me not being able to run

```
IRkernel::installspec()
```

to install the R kernel. In which case I get:

```
Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
```

Comment: Your bash profile excerpt seems incomplete, the `export PATH=` line seems to be cut off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip installs packages successfully, but executables not found from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line)

Comment: @JensV sorry, there was a typo: I have fixed it.

Comment: What's the output of `python3 -m site --user-base`?

Comment: @JensV /Users/myname/Library/Python/3.10

Comment: Check the second answer on the question I linked, it should solve your problem

Comment: @JensV I have added the path to my bash_profile. Now I have what follow:

`PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/$
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/Users/leonardogrotti/Library/Python/3.10/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: So does it work? Remember you have to source the bashrc or open a new terminal after changing the file

Comment: No, it still doesn't for some reason @JensV

Comment: How did you install jupyter? Did you use any or more of the following tools: pyenv, virtualenv, conda, pip, pipx, brew? It might also just be the case that the jupyter binary wasn't correctly added or it was deleted. Reinstalling might help in that case