# httpstat pip installed but not working as a command httpstat

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to use the Python library "[httpstat](https://pypi.org/project/httpstat/)".

[image]

As is mentioned on the official docs it says if I download it through pip I can use httpstat as command but I can't do that. It just throws the error that command isn't recognized.

[image]

As you can see it's already installed.

[image]

But I can't use it as a command.

Comment: `httpstat` is not in the PATH variable. Locate the binary and add it to the PATH.

More explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line

Comment: oh I really forgot that step... thanks for pointing out. it's working now... i do needed to figure out the location of the script where it's installed. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
python3 -m httpstat httpbin.org/get
```

It's should work

[image]

Comment: this does works but my query was regarding using httpstat as command... i did figure out .. thanks... I just needed to add httpstat in Environment variables of my system.